# How to find minimum and maximum of array of ints in assembler (SPARC)?

Tags: assembly, int, min, sparc

I have to write an assembly program that will find the minimum of array of ints (fed into the program from C as a pointer)

Can anyone tell me how to do it ? or at least how to store/access the array in assembler ?

Normally the variables are accessed by consecutive buffors e.g. :

```
subcc %i0, 2, %l0
```

but I don't have  a clue how to do it with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebember that in C expression `arr[i]` is in fact equivalent to `*(arr + i)`.

To access value in array you need to calculate it's address - it's `arr + i * sizeof(int)`. Then you can use `ld`, `st` instructions to read or write.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this somehow like this :

```
.global findminmax      !
.proc 4             !
                !
findminmax:         !
    save %sp, -96, %sp  !
    ld [%i0], %l0       !
    mov %l0, %l2        !
    mov %l0, %l3        !
                !
loop:               !
    subcc %i1, 1, %l0   !
    bneg end        !
    nop             !
                !
    ld [%i0], %l1       !
                !
    subcc %l2, %l1, %l0     !
    bneg newmax         !
    nop             !
                !
    subcc %l1, %l3, %l0     !
    bneg newmin         !
    nop             !
                !
back:           ! 
    add %i0, 4, %i0     !
    sub %i1, 1, %i1     !
    ba loop         !
    nop             !
end:                !
    st %l2, [%i2]       !
    st %l3, [%i3]       !
    ret             !
    restore         !
                !
newmax:             !
    mov %l1, %l2        !
    ba back         !
    nop             !
newmin:             !
    mov %l1, %l3        !
    ba back         !
    nop             !
```